# How to widen an object

Tags: objects

Im making a 3D model of a plane, so how do you widen a cylinder, im using references by the way. So I am trying to follow this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu9J0D6ebVw

Comment: Hi Justin. About the video if something particular is to be seen in it, corresponding to your question, please indicate at which minute it is... surely we cannot all spent 48' searching in it : ) !! thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu9J0D6ebVw look at minute 6 now how do I increase the size of the background? on mine it does not say size    .... just found it nvm!

Comment: sorry but normally size is visible... can you give a screen capture of your configuration for the background image ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu9J0D6ebVw if you go to the 7.40 his cylinder is invisable how did he do that? Mine shows a gray cylinder and is there anyway to post a image?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l_bTcHoZv2P7lGvuE7Rnvz4HPed9wrWXdtFSVQSvDV8/edit

Comment: Z key. Or the choice just on the right of 'object/edit/...' mode (on the bottom of the 3D view), which is the display/shading mode

Answer (score 0):

In object or edit mode, Press <kbd>S</kbd> to size and then press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to choose the axis.